# SDKMAN unable to insall on fedora

Tags: grails, sdkman, fedora-26

i want to install grails but seems that SDK tool must be installed first for productivity.

i m using fedor 26. to do :

sudo yum install unzip - its installed
sudo curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash

but noting happens ? 
nothing is drawn on the console. it just ends and expect another input on the terminal.

i tried to search .sdkman using find / name - .sdkman*
but not result found.

How do you do it then ? and why is curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
 not working ?

Comment: What is "nothing happens" and "not working"?  Please describe your actual errors etc.  Is the fetching of the file stalling?  Or does it stop with no error?  Are you behind a (corporate) firewall, that just drops disallowed connections?

Comment: @yes. corporate firewall yes i m but. i m installing packages using dnf i have exported proxy info. its shows nothing and says curl -s .... finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this:

You need to give proxy if you are using a corporate proxy firewall for curl.

```
curl -x http://<username>:<password>@<host>:<port> --proxy-anyaut -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash

if you get timeout at 443 chanage HTTPS of https://get.sdkman.io" to 
"http://get.sdkman.io" or make it like ""get.sdkman.io"
```

Then it works like a charm!